# Python 3.9 в macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, macos

Обновил с сайта http://python.org до последней версии - 3.9.1. При попытке запустить любой скрипт из консоли получаю:

```
zsh: operation not permitted: ./sample.py
```

[image: zsh: operation not permitted: ./sample.py]

Если запускаю как **python3 sample.py**, то всё работает.

UPD: Права на файл:
[image: права на файл]

UPD2: содержание файла:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

UPD3: новое содержание файла
[image: новое содержание файла]

Comment: Питно тут ни причём, вы просто должны выдать права на выполнение своему файлу (chmod и т.п.)

Comment: chmod +x делал - результат тот же. Добавил скриншот к вопросу.

Comment: Тогда в интернетах предлагают поправить доступы терминалу https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/ (хотя не уверен что это связано...)

Comment: @andreymal `Если запускаю как python3 sample.py, то всё работает.` ⇒ дело не в этом

Comment: @VictorVosMottor у python3 теоретически могут быть отдельные права доступа (но это не точно, я macos не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal полный доступ к диску Терминалу давал - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Посмотрите тут [how to change default python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5846167/3961199)

Comment: Что у вас показывает команда
which python
?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk which python - > /usr/bin/python

Comment: which python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

Comment: У вас в заголовке файла написано #!/usr/bin/python3. Если хотите python3, укажите путь, который вы увидели через команду which. Или поместите путь к python3 в PATH, и укажите в заголовке имя исполняемого  файла python3.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk не помогло. :(

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, какой в итоге получился заголовок вашего файла

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk добавил UPD3 в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Два момента:

- Не забудьте `chmod +x sample.py`
- И не забудьте шебанг: `#!/usr/bin/python` (это чтоб запустилось как питон, не связано с пермишеннами) ;)

Таким образом все должно работать.

Comment: Оба пункта сделаны - результат тот же. Добавил содержание файла в вопрос.

Comment: @str4n9er Так... не может быть ;D Вы что-то путаете...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor или вы чего-то не знаете о macos (и я тоже не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal Вряд ли ;D Я его довольно долго юзал. Такого не видел.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/561357)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков С чего бы это?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor судя по комментарию автора, ему не помог совсем ваш ответ, но ваш ответ подходит для комментария к вопросу по типу "Вы не забыли про 2 момента?"

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Ответ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ответом независимо от того, помог он или нет.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor вы говорите автору сделать, то что у него уже сделано было. То есть вы могли попросить автора "внести уточнения" по проблеме. Вы можете переместить свой ответ в комментарий под вопрос.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Если автор ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО сделал то, что я посоветовал, то у него всего ДОЛЖНО работать.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков неверные ответы тоже являются ответами

Comment: @andreymal Именно. И не только неверные, но и не сработавшие почему-то.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я еще раз повторю свою позицию. Вы могли все это уточнить у автора в комментарии, и он бы вам ответил "Оба пункта сделаны - результат тот же.", для этого комментарии и существуют. Для меня ваш ответ больше походит под комментарий, по этому я поставил его на удаление. Я понимаю, что и неверные ответы тоже ответы, но еще раз повторю, что ваш ответ я не считают ответом, как таковым. На этом предлагаю закончить.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor оба пункта были сделаны ещё до задачи вопроса на этом ресурсе.

Comment: @str4n9er У меня тоже был мак, zsh и питон — и все работало.